# Collecting items into a shell array

Tags: arrays, bash, loops

I have a shell script that iterates over a series of values in an array and executes a command on the item.

For any command that returns an error code != 0, I would like to add that to an array of failures for later display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I figured this out while formulating the question, here is the code I used:

```
#!/bin/bash -u

array=( repo1 repo2 repo3 )
errorarray=()
for i in "${array[@]}"; do
    cd $i && git pull || errorarray+=($i)
done


echo errorarray has ${#errorarray[@]} items

for e in "${errorarray[@]}"; do
    echo "$e failed"
done;

(( ${#errorarray[@]} == 0 )); 
exit $?
```

This has an added benefit of returning a non-zero if any of the sub-commands failed.

Comment: +1. I would replace the last paragraph with (add suitable newlines and indentation): `for e in "${errorarray[@]}"; do echo "$e failed"; done; (( ${#errorarray[@]} == 0 )); exit $?`

Comment: Note that `cd $i` is a double-edged weapon.  You may need to use `(cd $i && git checkout) || errorarray+=($i)`.  I'd prefer to see the `$i` in double quotes, but if there'll never be spaces in the names, you should be OK.

Comment: `git checkout` with no options? Why? If you're just checking for git directories use `GIT_DIR=${i}/.git git rev-parse --git-dir 2>/dev/null`. Though, even that will only tell about top-level directories and not any submodules. Also, you can just use `exit $((!!${#errorarray[@]}))`.

Comment: Typo, meant git pull. Point taken.